# Import 800K rows excel file to Access

Tags: excel, database, ms-access, import

I have an Excel file containing 800K rows and 80 columns and I want to import it in Access.
However, when I try to import it with the Import Wizard, I get differents errors everytime. This is because the file is too large.
Do you know a way to import such large files ?

Comment: What errors do you get? Some suggestions: 1.) Try saving as .csv and importing that 2.) Split the process up

Comment: I get "unexpected error from external database driver"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import huge 550000+ row CSV file into Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191012/import-huge-550000-row-csv-file-into-access)